# Two simple questions: definite integrals, differential calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Can someone verify if my solution to these two multiple-choice tasks are correct?

> Mark definite integrals:
>
> - 1: $\int_{2}^{4} x^2 - 3x + 4 dx$
> - 2: $\int 2\sin{x}dx$
> - 3: $\int_{0}^{3} \frac{\sin{x}}{2x - 3}dx$
> - 4: $\int_{-\infty}^{5}e^{-t} dt$
> - 5: $\int_{0}^{-5}1du$

$1$st integral is definite, $2$nd is indefinite, $3$rd is improper so does that count as definite? I think not., $4$th is also improper and $5$th is definite.

Hence, definite integrals: $1, 5$.

---

> Consider the differential equation: $y'' = \sin{x}$. Which statements
>   are true?
>
> - 1: it is a partial differential equation
> - 2: the order of this equation is $2$
> - 3: $y = -\sin{x} + 4$ is a particular solution of this equation
> - 4: $y = -\sin{x}$ is the general solution of this equation
> - 5: it is a linear differential equation

I chose: $2, 3, 5$ as correct answers.
Answer $4$ seems just wrong, because I think general solution would have some constant coefficient(s).

Thanks.

Comment: Your ideas about the second one (DE) is correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your answers are correct !

Comment: I cannot accept the post yet. So basically the conclusion is: improper integral is not a definite integral?